# How to subtract a row from the row above using a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am trying to learn how to use for loops in R, in particular to subtract a number from it's above number in a column in R.

I know can do this with `b <- diff(df$a)` or with:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(b = a - lag(a))
```

But I am trying to understand how I can also get the same result with something like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  result = df[2,] - df[i,]
  print (result)
}
```

How do I set this for loop so the `df[2,]` takes every following row, and not just the 2nd row, and subtracts from the row above?

For example I have data like this:

```
column a
1
10
20
```

and I want to eventually create a column with the subtractions:

```
column a    column b
1             10
11            9
20           ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` loop like

```
df$columnB <- NA

for(i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
   df$columnB[i] = df$columnA[i+1] - df$columnA[i]
}
df
#  columnA columnB
#1       1      10
#2      11       9
#3      20       5
#4      25       9
#5      34      NA
```

**data**

Sample data used:

```
df <- data.frame(columnA  =  c(1, 11, 20, 25, 34))
```

Comment: This is perfect, and I understand how it works within the loop now, thank you! (will click the tick as soon as it allows me to)